# web scraping JOINURL stub and scraped page href

Tags: pandas, web-scraping, python-requests

I am trying to join a web-scraped href to the main url of the website (Stub), then pass it to a full_url []. I can't get it to work, any ideas?

```
import pandas as pd
import requests
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
from urllib import parse
from urllib.parse import urljoin

url = 'http://www.owgr.com/events?pageNo=1&pageSize=400&tour=Eur&year=2019'
stub = 'http://www.owgr.com'
page = requests.get(url, headers=headers)
soup = BeautifulSoup(page.text, 'html.parser')


full_url = []

full_url_elem = soup.find_all(id='ctl5')  

for item in full_url_elem:
    full_url.item.find('a').get('href')
    full_url.append(item(urljoin('stub', 'event_url'))
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are a few issues here:

You are iterateing through your `full_url_elem` which is good, but what is `full_url.item.find('a').get('href')` suppose to do? Get rid of `full_url`.

What you want is to get the `<a>` tag from `item`, then get the `href` from that. Secondly, you'll need to fix what you are wanting to join.

```
for item in full_url_elem:
    full_url.item.find('a').get('href')  # <--- remove full_url
    full_url.append(item(urljoin('stub', 'event_url'))  # <--- just use the + to combine 2 strings, and what is event_url? Also, you joining the string `'stub'` and the string `'event_url'` which will return `stubevent_url`, when what you really want is the variable `stub` and variable `event_url`
```

Here's what it should look like:

```
import pandas as pd
import requests
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
from urllib import parse
from urllib.parse import urljoin


headers = {'User-Agent': 'Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; Win64; x64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/76.0.3809.132 Safari/537.36'}

url = 'http://www.owgr.com/events?pageNo=1&pageSize=400&tour=Eur&year=2019'
stub = 'http://www.owgr.com'
page = requests.get(url, headers=headers)
soup = BeautifulSoup(page.text, 'html.parser')


full_url = []

full_url_elem = soup.find_all(id='ctl5')  

for item in full_url_elem:
    event_url = item.find('a').get('href')
    full_url.append(stub + event_url)
```

**Output:**

```
print (full_url)
['http://www.owgr.com/en/Events/EventResult.aspx?eventid=7631', 'http://www.owgr.com/en/Events/EventResult.aspx?eventid=7621', 'http://www.owgr.com/en/Events/EventResult.aspx?eventid=7611', 'http://www.owgr.com/en/Events/EventResult.aspx?eventid=7599', 'http://www.owgr.com/en/Events/EventResult.aspx?eventid=7587', 'http://www.owgr.com/en/Events/EventResult.aspx?eventid=7562', 'http://www.owgr.com/en/Events/EventResult.aspx?eventid=7555', 'http://www.owgr.com/en/Events/EventResult.aspx?eventid=7554', 'http://www.owgr.com/en/Events/EventResult.aspx?eventid=7538', 'http://www.owgr.com/en/Events/EventResult.aspx?eventid=7516', 'http://www.owgr.com/en/Events/EventResult.aspx?eventid=7507', 'http://www.owgr.com/en/Events/EventResult.aspx?eventid=7493', 'http://www.owgr.com/en/Events/EventResult.aspx?eventid=7480', 'http://www.owgr.com/en/Events/EventResult.aspx?eventid=7457', 'http://www.owgr.com/en/Events/EventResult.aspx?eventid=7440', 'http://www.owgr.com/en/Events/EventResult.aspx?eventid=7427', 'http://www.owgr.com/en/Events/EventResult.aspx?eventid=7415', 'http://www.owgr.com/en/Events/EventResult.aspx?eventid=7403', 'http://www.owgr.com/en/Events/EventResult.aspx?eventid=7388', 'http://www.owgr.com/en/Events/EventResult.aspx?eventid=7374', 'http://www.owgr.com/en/Events/EventResult.aspx?eventid=7369', 'http://www.owgr.com/en/Events/EventResult.aspx?eventid=7364', 'http://www.owgr.com/en/Events/EventResult.aspx?eventid=7359', 'http://www.owgr.com/en/Events/EventResult.aspx?eventid=7346', 'http://www.owgr.com/en/Events/EventResult.aspx?eventid=7329', 'http://www.owgr.com/en/Events/EventResult.aspx?eventid=7323', 'http://www.owgr.com/en/Events/EventResult.aspx?eventid=7314', 'http://www.owgr.com/en/Events/EventResult.aspx?eventid=7304', 'http://www.owgr.com/en/Events/EventResult.aspx?eventid=7302', 'http://www.owgr.com/en/Events/EventResult.aspx?eventid=7297', 'http://www.owgr.com/en/Events/EventResult.aspx?eventid=7290']
```